# If thermonuclear weapons can explode, what's to say a fusion reactor won't?

Tags: fusion

They are fundamentally the same reaction. People say that if something goes wrong plasma will expand and cool, not explode. However, what's to say when we achieve q>1 it won't explode? If it won't, how do hydrogen bombs work?

Comment: One has to put some effort to make a nuclear bomb actually _explode_ (to its design power). You may want to learn about the concept of [fizzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizzle_(nuclear_explosion)).

Comment: Another point is the fusion in a 'hydrogen bomb' is there to provide lots of energetic neutrons to the secondary to kick start the fission reaction. Very little energy output is from the fusion proper - DT fusion yields about 17MeV, U fission about 180MeV.

Answer (score 3):

The chemical reactions making a log in a fireplace burn are fundamentally the same kind of reactions as when gasoline is burning (and not too far off from TNT exploding). That reactions are similar does not mean the overall process of energy release behaves the same way.

A lot hinges on how rapidly the fusion rate increases by temperature and pressure, and the timescale for energy to leave the region. Thermonuclear weapons work by confining fusion fuel in a rapidly imploding region where it "burns" quickly (and then expands as an explosion because of it). A fusion reactor works by confining fusion fuel in a magnetic field that responds to the temperature and pressure on basically the same timescale: if it expands temperature and fusion rate goes down. Note that it is not acting in the self-amplifying chain reaction mode of a fission reactor.